# Custom file validation before upload : how to set file status to invalid?

Tags: filepond

I need to use some custom validation before uploading files (using FilePond).

Is there a way to set file status, after some validation stuff ?

For ex., a file is dropped, then some validation stuff is done, and if validation fails this file is "marked" as invalid and won't be processed.
Something like what validation size plugin does by itself.

I hope my question is precise enough.

Thnaks for your answer.

JG